# approximation symbol with a letter under it

Tags: symbols

How to write the (approximation iniquity) with a letter under it on latex?
[image]

Comment: One of the options at [Is there an “underscript” command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/is-there-an-underscript-command) should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\underset{A}{\approx}`

`\overset{A}{\approx}` puts the A over the sign. AMS required.